# Integration of ODE

Tags: integration

dh/dt = -2k((h)^0.5) - where k is a constant

Need to find the value of equation h(t). I have tried separating variables and found h(t)=(-kt-kc)^0.5

Is this correct?

Comment: The equation is $$\frac{dh}{dt}=-2k\sqrt h$$??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $\frac{dh}{dt}=-2k\sqrt h$ is indeed separable, and we have
$$\frac{dh}{2\sqrt h}=-kdt\\\int\frac{1}{2\sqrt h}dh=\int -kdt +C\\\sqrt h=-kt+C$$